Kotlin access outer class from inner class's constructor throw NPE, why?
Kotlin access outer class from inner class's constructor throw NPE
this piece of code works as expected:
https://pl.kotl.in/xaSu-xe9u
interface M {
    fun hello()
}

abstract class Parent : M {
    init {
        this.hello()
    }
}

class Outer : M {
    override fun hello() {
        println("hello, world")
    }

    inner class Inner : Parent(), M by this {
        override fun hello() {
            this@Outer.hello()
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val out = Outer()
    val inner = out.Inner()
}

but the code below throws NPE:
https://pl.kotl.in/PfogCZBSW
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Outer.hello()" because "this.$$delegate_0" is null
    at Outer$Inner.hello(Bug.kt)
    at Parent.<init>(Bug.kt:9)
    at Outer$Inner.<init>(Bug.kt:18)
    at BugKt.main(Bug.kt:23)
    at BugKt.main(Bug.kt)

interface M {
    fun hello()
}

abstract class Parent : M {
    init {
        this.hello()
    }
}

class Outer : M {
    override fun hello() {
        println("hello, world")
    }

    inner class Inner : Parent(), M by this
}

fun main() {
    val out = Outer()
    val inner = out.Inner()
}

why? is this a compiler bug?

Never call open functions or properties from a constructor—it’s unsafe in various ways. I’m surprised they did not decide to make it a compiler error to do that.

We could argue if this is a compiler bug or not, but I think messing up with the object initialization like this is asking for trouble. Calling an abstract function in the constructor is itself a red flag for me. You use multiple advanced features like delegation and hope everything will work in the exact order you need. It could work or not.
We can find the exact explanation in the generated bytecode for the Inner constructor:
   L0
    LINENUMBER 22 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    PUTFIELD Outer$Inner.this$0 : LOuter;
    ALOAD 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 22 L1
    INVOKESPECIAL Parent.<init> ()V
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    PUTFIELD Outer$Inner.$$delegate_0 : LOuter;
    RETURN

First, it sets the this@Outer, then it calls the super constructor and only then it sets the M delegate. Which makes sense if we consider that the parent constructor is generally executed before initializing the child class and its members. It also matches the order we see in the source code: Parent(), M by this. Parent constructor is called while the delegation is not yet initialized.
Please note Kotlin documentation even mentions this specific case as one of very few scenarios where the NPE may actually happen in Kotlin:

The only possible causes of an NPE in Kotlin are: (...) A superclass constructor calls an open member whose implementation in the derived class uses an uninitialized state.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-nullable-types
On the other hand, there are no technical reasons your specific case can't be supported. If the compiler initialize the delegate before executing the parent constructor, or if it doesn't introduce another field, but reuse the this@Outer for delegation, your code would work. Your first example actually proofs this is technically possible. As a matter of fact, Kotlin compiler already provides optimizations to not introduce this additional field in some cases, but unfortunately, it doesn't optimize the "delegate to outer class" case. Maybe it will in the future and it that case, your code will work just fine. Still, I don't think we can say this is a compiler bug. It is simply not supported as of Kotlin 1.9.x .

but... I want the derived classes to implement some part of the construction code, how to achieve this?

@TanTelephone This is a kind of chicken-egg problem. Normally, we assume the subclass logic depends on the logic of the superclass, we assume the superclass is fully initialized at the time we start initializing the subclass. This assumption is not specific to Kotlin or Java, it is a common thing. Now, you try to do the opposite - your superclass depends on the subclass. To initialize the subclass, we need to first initialize the superclass, but to initialize the superclass, we need to first initialize the subclass.

@TanTelephone This pattern where a derived class provides some kind of an initialization behavior for the superclass, could work in some cases - mostly if that provided behavior would be almost static. However, if it requires the subtype to be already initialized, then it can't really work. As a rule of thumb, I think we should keep constructors as simple as possible. Only initialize some fields and that's it. If we need some more complicated logic, it is safer to put it outside of constructor and call it explicitly.

This is not a compiler bug. According to the Kotlin Language Specification, the evaluation of the delegation expression happens after the initialisation of the superclass:

[...] the following happens, in this initialization order:

The superclass object is initialized as if created by invoking sctor with the specified parameters;
Interface delegation expressions are invoked and the result of each is stored in the object to allow for interface delegation, in the
order of appearance of delegation declarations in the supertype
specifier list;
[...]


When the init block in Parent runs, this@Outer has not been "stored in the object to allow for interface delegation" yet. On the JVM, this means the delegate object is null.
This proves that you cannot have such a design that uses delegation. You should rethink your design, or implement each M method explicitly.
See also the inheritance delegation section, which explains what code M by this is lowered to. This section also explains why the first code snippet works. The delegation M by this will not overwrite your existing explicit implementation of hello: (Emphasis mine)

If inherited using delegation, each method M of I (whether they have a default implementation or not) is delegated to the corresponding method of v as if it was overridden in C with all the parameter values directly passed to the corresponding method in v, unless the body of C itself has a suitable override of M


Instead of having an abstract Parent, You can have a concrete Parent that takes in an M and uses that as the delegate.
open class Parent(m: M): M by m {
    init {
        hello()
    }
}

inner class Inner : Parent(this)

But then you would not be able to explicitly implement the abstract methods of M in a subclass.
